# The result from Print (@SQLquery) differs from stored procedure exact result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is my query

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[OpenExcel]

  @FileName        Varchar(2000),
  @ExcelName       Varchar(2000),
  @SheetName       Varchar(100) ,
  @Header          Varchar(50)  ,
  @WhereClause     Varchar(1000),
  @DesiredColumn   Varchar(1000) 
AS 
Begin
   DECLARE @Provider Nvarchar(2000);
       SET @Provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';
   DECLARE @DateKey Varchar(50)
       SET @DateKey = Substring(Right(@ExcelName,8),1,4) +'/'+Substring(Right(@ExcelName,8),5,2)+'/'+Substring(Right(@ExcelName,8),7,2)

   DECLARE @date datetime       
       SET @date = GETDATE()

   DECLARE @SQLQuery Nvarchar(MAX)

   IF (rtrim(ltrim(@SheetName)) = '') -- If SheetName Is NULL
    Begin 
        SET @SheetName = 'sheet1'
    End

    IF (rtrim(ltrim(@DesiredColumn)) = '') -- If Desired Columns are NULL
    Begin 
        SET @DesiredColumn = '*'
    End
--*****************
      Set @SQLQuery = 
         ' SELECT ' + ' ' + @DesiredColumn +' '+ QUOTENAME(@ExcelName,'''') +' AS ExcelName ,' + QUOTENAME(@date,'''') + ' AS TimeStamp' +', '+
         + @DateKey +''+' AS DateKey
          FROM OPENROWSET (''' + @Provider + ''',''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @FileName +';hdr='+@Header+''+''',
                     ''SELECT * FROM ['+ @SheetName+'$]'')'                  

if (rtrim(ltrim(@WhereClause)) <> '') -- IF there is a Where Clause
    begin 
        set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + @WhereClause
    end

   Print (@SQLQuery)
   EXEC  (@SQLQuery)

END
```

I see something weird when executing this query.
the problem is in "DateKe" column .
as you can see below it gives me the exact form of the datekey I want

[image]

But i see something different in the result set as you can see below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the DateKey value.

Without quotes it looks like (and is treated like) a number: 1397 divided by 01 divided by 01 is 1397.